# How to make me return zero instead of null?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(total) relustadodelasuma 
FROM   
(SELECT total FROM pedido 
WHERE  fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT total 
FROM registro 
WHERE fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' ) X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFNULL()` operator like below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total),0) relustadodelasuma 
FROM   
(SELECT total FROM pedido 
WHERE  fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT total FROM registro 
WHERE fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' ) X
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL()`.

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(total),0) relustadodelasuma 
from 
(SELECT IFNULL(total,0) from pedido 
where fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' union all 
SELECT IFNULL(total,0) 
FROM 
registro where fecha >= '2019-03-01' AND fecha < '2019-04-01' );
```

IFNULL() checks the first expression(param), if its not null then returns the value, or if its null then returns the second expression(param).

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull